# c programming shallow line fix

Tags: c

I have a main function below, however, the line - gets(newstring); never get prompted, and the program skips the get and insert lines, i was told that could be a shallow line issue, but I dont know what is that mean and how to fix it, please help, thanks,

```
int main() {
    char newstring [25];
    int removeelem;
    int findelem;

    struct data_node *first=NULL, *ptr;

    printf ("Enter list command (+-flx): ");
    scanf (" %c", &key);

    switch (key) {
    case '+':
            printf ("+ detected \n");
            printf ("Enter key data: \n");
            scanf ("%D", &newelem);
            printf ("What string to store? \n");
            gets(newstring);
            insert(&first, newelem,newstring);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `key` for debugging purposes. Where did you declare `key`? `gets()` is deprecated and will cause undefined behaviour if the input is longer than 24 characters. It is bad style to declare multiple pointers in one line. Check the return value of scanf, it probably fails because it expects a space before the character. You have unneeded spaces at the ends of your printed lines. Is that enough for the beginning?

Comment: Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf ("%D", &newelem);
```

When you entering the number, you hitting 'return' key. `'\n'` symbol is still left in file buffer, because you haven't asked `scanf` to read it too. Next time you call `gets` it reads one *line*, which is 0 symbols - it sees `'\n'` immediately.

To fix your problem, you need to either remove `'\n'` manually (e.g. by dummy `gets`), or by using

```
scanf ("%D\n", &newelem);
```

By the way, try to avoid `gets`. This function is dangerous because it don't know size limit on buffer, and any modern compiler will warn you loudly not to use it. Try to use `fgets` instead.